# $('#some-id').on('click', function (event) {} how to convert to function called in php echo'';

Tags: javascript

how can convert this to function workin in echo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      $('#notific8Family').on(
        'change',
        function(event) {
          $family = $(event.currentTarget);
          family = $family.val()
          $theme = $('#notific8Theme')
          $theme.find('option:selected').prop('selected', false);
          $theme.find('option').hide();
          $theme.find('option[data-for="' + family + '"]').show()
          $theme.find('option[data-for="' + family + '"][data-selected]').prop('selected', true)
        }
      )

      $('#notific8Test').on('click', function (event) {
        var params = {
            life: $('#notific8Life').find('option:selected').val(),
            family: $('#notific8Family').find('option:selected').val(),
            theme: $('#notific8Theme').val(),
            sticky: $('#notific8Sticky').is(':checked'),
            horizontalEdge: $('#notific8horizontal').find('option:selected').val(),
            verticalEdge: $('#notific8vertical').find('option:selected').val(),
            onInit: function(data) {
              if (window.console) {
                console.log('--onInit--');
                console.log('data:');
                console.log(data);
              }
            },
            onCreate: function(notification, data) {
              if (window.console) {
                console.log('--onCreate--');
                console.log('notification:');
                console.log(notification);
                console.log('data:');
                console.log(data);
              }
            },
            onClose: function(notification, data) {
              if (window.console) {
                console.log('--onClose--');
                console.log('notification:');
                console.log(notification);
                console.log('data:');
                console.log(data);
              }
            }
          },
          text = $('#notific8Text').val(),
          $heading = $('#notific8Heading'),
          $closeText = $('#notific8CloseText'),
          $icon = $('#notific8Icon');

        if ($.trim($heading.val()) !== '') {
          params.heading = $heading.val();
        }
        if ($.trim($icon.val()) !== '') {
          params.icon = $icon.val();
        }
        if ($.trim($closeText.val()) !== '') {
          params.closeText = $closeText.val();
        }

        // show notification
        $.notific8(text, params);
      });

      $('#notific8Family').trigger('change');
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: Huh!!! You want to print the code or run the function with `echo`?

Comment: Although people could (and probably will) answer you it makes no sense and this is clearly an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). This would also be solved by writing a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @aboody Why would you want to do that?

Comment: yes i would run the function with echo, but how?

Comment: it's just work in click

Comment: Can you tell exactly the reasons and/or the problems you are getting which leads you to think of running that function with an `echo`? You should specify what your problem is, not just asking something you want to be done without citing the reasons/problems behind.  :)

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
ob_start();
?>
    /* your stuff :) */
<?php
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo $output;
```

this will write the whole stuff into the variable **$output**
Search for **ob_start** and **ob_get_contents** on the internet

Comment: i am don't understand you

Comment: It seams that I misunderstood your question. I tough you just simply want to  print out the text-block containing a JS function. What do you want to do with this code?